# How to PartitionBy a column in spark and drop the same column before saving the dataframe in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say we have have a dataframe with columns as col1, col2, col3, col4. Now while saving the df I want to partition by using col2 and my final df which will be saved should not have col2. So the final df should be col1, col3, col4. Any advice about how should can I achieve this?

```
newdf.drop("Status").write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Status").csv("C:/Users/Documents/Test")
```

Comment: By default it will not save partitionBy column along with data., can you post your code ?

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drop` will drop status column & Your code will fail with below error at `partitionBy` as `status` column was dropped.

`` org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Partition column `status` not found in schema [...] ``

Check below code, It will not include `status` values inside your data.

```
newdf
.write
.mode("overwrite")
.partitionBy("Status")
.csv("C:/Users/Documents/Test")
```

Comment: If the `Status` column is part of the df how come it's not in the output data?